# Best practice to call function inside route methode

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm new to flask and in order to refactor an existing route method on a Flask API, i'm looking for the best practice to reduce it and call method inside the route method.

Acutally the route is designed like that :

```
@qman.route('/add_report/', methods=['POST'])
def create_report():
   """
   Check if data send throught http POST request, is correct based on the report
   schema and not already recorded in the table report of the DB.
   :param: data from POST request
   :return: Ok, valide and imported -> 201, Correct but AlreadyKnown -> 208, 
   InvalideScheme -> 422
   """
   jsonData = request.get_json()
   reportSchema = ReportSchema()  
   try:
      data = reportSchema.load(jsonData)
   except ValidationError as validation_err:
      return(validation_err.messages), 422
    
   nameReportCheck = data["report_name"]
   report = Report.query.filter_by(report_name=nameReportCheck).first()
   
   if report is None:
      # Create new report
      report = Report(
      report_name=nameReportCheck,
      hostname=data["hostname"],
      status=data["status"],
      date=data["date"],
      nb_analysis_erreur=data["nb_analysis_erreur"]
      )

      db.session.add(report)
      db.session.commit()

      NewResult = reportSchema.dump(Report.query.get(report.reportID))
      return{"message" : "Created new report" , "report" : NewResult}, 201

   else :
      reportAlreadyKnown = reportSchema.dump(Report.query.get(report.reportID))
      return{"message" : "This report is already in the DB", "report" : reportAlreadyKnown}, 208
```

In the facts i would like to call a function named `valid_schema(_schema, _jsondata)` to check if the data send throught POST request match with my schema of model `Report()`.

This function return a Response() object with serialized data and a 200 code if it's serialization is possible or an error that i cath inside try/except with 400 error code.

```
def valid_schema(_schema, _jsondata):
    schema = _schema()
    try:
      data = schema.load(_jsondata)
    except ValidationError as validation_err:
        response = Response(validation_err.messages, 422)
        return response
    response = Response(data, 200, mimetype="application/json")
    return response
```

Then the route method call an other function named `create_report(report_data)` if `valid_schema(_schema, _jsondata)` return report_data and 200 code in response object.

With his args, this method check if the records is not already in the DB and if is not, he create a `Report()` object from `report_data arg` and insert this one as a new record into the DB.

In fact I guess I can easily call this method inside the route function but it seem weird and there is probably an other way that I can't find, maybe decorator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for refactoring is the use of [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), [Flask-Marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

With Flask-Marshmallow you can check the input by specifying fields and validators. Webargs offers you the option of validating the defined scheme in a decorator and passing it on to the route as an argument. Using marshmallow-sqlalchemy in combination, this is immediately converted into a database model.

The following example is based on your information and gives you a brief overview of the usage. By defining your own [error handler](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/#returning-api-errors-as-json), the error messages can also be sent as JSON. Use in blueprints, views or the like is possible.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow.validate import Length, OneOf
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class Report(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    hostname = db.Column(db.String)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    nb_analysis_error = db.Column(db.String)

class ReportSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        load_instance = True
        sqla_session = db.session

    name = ma.Str(required=True, validate=Length(min=3))
    hostname = ma.Str(required=True)
    date = ma.DateTime(required=True)
    status = ma.Str(required=True, validate=OneOf(['online', 'offline']))
    nb_analysis_error = ma.Str(missing='Unknown Error')

@app.route('/add_report', methods=['POST'])
@use_args(ReportSchema(), location='json')
def add_report(report):
    report_schema = ReportSchema()
    _report = Report.query.filter_by(name=report.name).first()
    if _report:
        report_data = report_schema.dump(_report)
        return jsonify(message='Already Reported', report=report_data), 208
    else:
        db.session.add(report)
        db.session.commit()
        report_data = report_schema.dump(report)
        return jsonify(message='Created', report=report_data), 201

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
```